# Is there any minGW-w64 documentation of C functions?

Tags: mingw-w64

Most of the C code for my project appears to be almost OS independent or, perhaps, I should write the same in each OS.

However, attempting to programmatically rename and move directories required Windows-specific information. The minGW-W64 site sends you to Source Forge but there is almost nothing there. The functions are different than the GNU/GCC documentation and man pages. Searching led to Microsoft links such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/rename-wrename?view=msvc-160 which were helpful but what's there doesn't always fit what minGW-W64 does?

For example, the above Microsoft documentation states that a directory can be renamed but not moved using the `rename()` function. However, it works in my code tests. I didn't set out to test it, but made a mistake in a directory path and it successfully moved a directory and its contents to a new location.

My question is where can one find documentation on minGW-W64 that is accurate? Or is there not any comparable to that for linux?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MinGW Windows header should be compatible with MSDN documentation, hence it doesn't provide its own. In fact, it links with Windows own libraries for those functions, which is provided by the OS, so if there's any behavioral inconsistencies, it comes from Windows, not MinGW.

Comment: I looked in `stdio.h` and can see that there is nothing there for rename but a call to Windows rename. The Windows documentation was dated 4/2020; so, it's not that old. I'm still working on machine running Windows 7; perhaps that has something to do with it. Thanks.